# Keycloak | Configuration H2 database - dev-file or dev-mem

Tags: jdbc, keycloak, h2

I try to deploy Keycloak 18 on kubernetes with dev-mem (or dev-file) database. I prepared deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak-quarkus
  namespace: keycloak-quarkus-dev
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak-quarkus
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - args:
            - '-v'
            - start
            - '--auto-build'
            - '--db=dev-mem'
            - '--health-enabled=true'
          env:
            - name: KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: password
                  name: keystore-password
            - name: TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: password
                  name: truststore-password
            - name: KC_HTTP_ENABLED
              value: 'true'
            - name: KC_HOSTNAME
              value: keycloak-quarkus-dev.mywebsite.com
            - name: KC_HTTPS_KEY_STORE_FILE
              value: /certs/keystore.p12
            - name: KC_HTTPS_TRUST_STORE_FILE
              value: /certs/truststore.jks
            - name: KC_HTTPS_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: password
                  name: keystore-password
            - name: KC_HTTPS_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: password
                  name: truststore-password
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: username
                  name: admin-credentials
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  key: password
                  name: admin-credentials
            - name: KC_DB_USERNAME
              value: sa
            - name: KC_DB_PASSWORD
              value: sa
            - name: KC_DB_URL
              value: 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb'
          image: 'quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2'
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /health/live
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 100
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 2
          name: keycloak-quarkus
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
            - containerPort: 8443
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /health/ready
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 2
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /certs/keystore.p12
              name: keystore
              readOnly: true
              subPath: keystore.p12
            - mountPath: /certs/truststore.jks
              name: truststore
              readOnly: true
              subPath: truststore.jks
            - mountPath: /certs/whitelist.yaml
              name: mtls-whitelist
              readOnly: true
              subPath: whitelist.yaml
      volumes:
        - configMap:
            name: keystore
          name: keystore
        - configMap:
            name: truststore
          name: truststore
        - configMap:
            name: whitelist
          name: mtls-whitelist
```

After apply keycloak runs but I get issue "An internal server error has occurred".
In logs I get error:

```
2022-07-21 09:29:42,720 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (executor-thread-0) Table "USER_ENTITY" not found; SQL statement:
select count(userentity0_.ID) as col_0_0_ from USER_ENTITY userentity0_ where userentity0_.REALM_ID=? and (userentity0_.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_LINK is null) [42102-197]
2022-07-21 09:29:42,734 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (executor-thread-0) Uncaught server error: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.services.resources.QuarkusWelcomeResource.createWelcomePage(QuarkusWelcomeResource.java:215)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.services.resources.QuarkusWelcomeResource.getWelcomePage(QuarkusWelcomeResource.java:95)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:408)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:151)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:82)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:42)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1212)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:163)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:141)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:67)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:55)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1212)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:163)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:141)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$5.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:380)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$5.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:358)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1212)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:163)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:141)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.integration.web.QuarkusRequestFilter.lambda$createBlockingHandler$1(QuarkusRequestFilter.java:71)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$null$0(ContextImpl.java:159)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:100)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:157)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$13.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:543)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

After a while I get many similar errors, for example:

```
2022-07-21 09:33:36,874 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (Timer-0) Table "REALM" not found; SQL statement:
select distinct realmentit0_.EVENTS_EXPIRATION as col_0_0_ from REALM realmentit0_ where realmentit0_.EVENTS_EXPIRATION>0 [42102-197]
2022-07-21 09:33:36,877 ERROR [org.keycloak.services] (Timer-0) KC-SERVICES0089: Failed to run scheduled task ClearExpiredEvents: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

I suppose, it's the problem with incorrect configuration database. I can't find in documentation how to configure dev-mem datebase, what environment variables should I set and what values shoud they have (my username "sa" and password "sa" are taken from another post).
I know that dev-mem (or dev-file) shoudn't be use in production environment but I woud like run keycloak in production mode anyway

Comment: A guess from my side: the production mode uses KC_CACHE=ispn by default. This might notwork with h2. Can you try setting KC_CACHE=local instead? But not sure it helps, never triedand cant recommend using h2, tbh. It has cve's.